# How to get a collection or array of all nested enums declared inside another enum?

Tags: java, java-8

For testing support I have the following enum. It is about `I18n`.

```
public enum PersonaFieldI18n {

    NOTHING_TO_DO;

    private PersonaFieldI18n(){

    }

    public enum English {

        ID("Id"),
        NOMBRE("Name"),
        APELLIDO("Last Name"),
        FECHA("Date");

        private String field;

        private English(String field){
            this.field = field;
        }

        public String getField() {
            return field;
        }

    }

    public enum Spanish {

        ID("Id"),
        NOMBRE("Nombre"),
        APELLIDO("Apellido"),
        FECHA("Fecha");

        private String field;

        private Spanish(String field){
            this.field = field;
        }

        public String getField() {
            return field;
        }

    }

    public enum Portuguese {

        ID("Id"),
        NOMBRE("Nome"),
        APELLIDO("Sobrenome"),
        FECHA("Data");

        private String field;

        private Portuguese(String field){
            this.field = field;
        }

        public String getField() {
            return field;
        }

    }
}
```

If `PersonaFieldI18n.values()` is executed, it only returns `NOTHING_TO_DO`.

What is the approach (if one exists) to get a collection or array with each nested enum?

I need a way to call a method defined within the `PersonaFieldI18n` enum where it returns the following elements:

- `PersonaFieldI18n.English`
- `PersonaFieldI18n.Spanish`
- `PersonaFieldI18n.Portuguese`

As you can see, each element shown above is a nested enum of the `PersonaFieldI18n` enum.

Is doing this possible? How? What is the best implementation?

Comment: You do know this is a really bad way to do I18N, right?

Comment: Let me know a better approach. Thanks in advance. Remember it is for testing purposes.

Comment: "Nested" enums are really just static inner classes. You could iterate over them with reflection.

Comment: @Kevin Could you share that approach how an answer? it to let me test it and apply how a valid answer. Thanks

Comment: Well, I18N isn't a new thing, so there's dozens of possible ways to implement it in a smart way, depending on what other technologies you're using. Hand coding enums is one of the weirder ones I've seen.

Comment: The proper way to do I18N is with [java.util.ResourceBundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html), which is literally made for this.

Comment: I see your approach, and I use Spring's `MessageSource` based practically `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`. I am agree with your valid suggestion. But to let me test the correct loaded data through `I18n` from `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` I am using this kind of enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @Kevin saying Nested enums are really inner classes of PersonaFieldI18n, so you can get them by *reflection*.

the statement as below:

```
Class<?>[] classes = PersonaFieldI18n.class.getDeclaredClasses();
```